# PHP not executing all given statements

Tags: php, mysql

As most of you following in this thread know, I have had problems sending bulk sms using for loop and if statements. However I have reduced my query to the following. I am only using AND's and repeating the query for each immunization date

```
    $getnumbers="SELECT
    guardian_records.First_Name,
    guardian_records.ID, 
    guardian_records.Cellphone_Number,
    children_records.Child_First_Name,
    children_records.Guardian_ID,
    children_records.ID,
    immunization_records.child_ID,
    immunization_records.First_Immunization_Date,        
FROM
    guardian_records,
    children_records,
    immunization_records
WHERE
    guardian_records.ID = children_records.Guardian_ID
    AND children_records.ID = immunization_records.child_ID
    AND immunization_records.First_Immunization_Date = CURDATE()";


$check =  mysql_query($getnumbers); 
$found =  mysql_num_rows($check);  
$details=mysql_fetch_assoc ($check);
$date1=$details['First_Immunization_Date']; 
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$today = strtotime($todays_date);    
$immunization_date1 = strtotime($date1);

if($immunization_date1 == $today) 

for($counter=0;$counter<$found;$counter++)
{
 $date  = $date1; 
 $shots = "Polio and Diptheria";    

$cellphonenumber=$details['Cellphone_Number']; 
$childname=$details['Child_First_Name']; 
$parentname=$details['First_Name'];
$msg="Dear $parentname, your child $childname is due for $shots shots on $date which is today. Message sent by Maisha Reminder System";
$encmsg=urlencode($msg);  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=Maisha&password=m123456&to=$cellphonenumber&text=$encmsg");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
} 
}
```

The way I have done it is I have the above code in the same page repeated four times for each possible immunization. However PHP does not execute the whole statement. It only does the first stack then stops. E.g using the above example code, it only executes this bit and leaves out the rest of the code which is exactly the same as the one above with relevant changes

Is there a way to make sure PHP executes ALL given statements. Does the FOR loop or the IF statement prevent execution of all statements if the condition is satisfied? All help appreciated.

Comment: I assume then that one guardian may have multiple immunization ids, and you want to make sure that you only send one message per guardian that includes all possible immunization ids?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one Guardian can have multiple ImmunizationIds, and you want to send a single text message to a particular phone number, you could take an approach like this:

```
$guardians = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($yourResultSet)){
    if(isset($guardians[$row['Cellphone_Number']])){  //Make sure that your phone number has been initialized 
        $guardians[$row['Cellphone_Number']] .= "Text too add to message for this immunization";
    }else{
        $guardians[$row['Cellphone_Number']] = "Text too add to message for this immunization";
    }
}


foreach($guardians as $phoneNumber => $textMessage){
    sendMessage($phoneNumber, $textMessage); //where sendMessage is the function you use to send the text message
}
```

You could also do this in a more OO way, but this should suffice to get your started.  Of course you'll also need to make sure you've got your sanity checks in 'sendMessage' in the event that the message ends up longer than 140 characters, but that isn't part of this question.

Comment: I would use arrays of immunization IDs instead of just appending strings, and then build the message before sending; however, I guess this is what he meant..

Comment: In general I agree, redShadow.  Was just trying to keep it as simple  as possible.

Comment: I ended up using a for loop with an array. But I get a pecular error. The first sms are correct but the rest uses the first kid in my table and all the shots in the database due to the dates I think

Comment: What if you add a DISTINCT to your select statement?  It looks like, because you are using OR, that you might end up with the same results a couple of different times.  That would potentially lead to the issue you are running into.  But using DISTINCT then each single record will only be processed one time.